# Does enabling Kerberos require a server reboot?

Tags: windows, sql-server, domain-controller, kerberos

We are going to enable Kerberos to allow double hop authentication between our SQL Servers. Our company is nearly 24 hours which leaves a very small window for server restarts. Is it possible to enable Kerberos without requiring a reboot of our Domain Controllers or our SQL servers?

Comment: You're changing authentication schemes on a 24-hour company without a test environment?

Comment: point taken! I'll have to check with the hardware/network folks about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerberos is already enabled, it's how active directory works, what I assume your talking about is enabling delegation from your web server(or other application server) to your SQL server, this does not require a reboot.

That said, as pboin mentioned, I would always try this in a test environment first.

Comment: Certainly a valid point. This actually did come up in discussions. I'm not sure how well we'll be able to create a test environment to mimic this. But it's definitely worth exploring more.

Comment: Our authentication is defaulting to NTLM. We are looking to default to Kerberos. Leaving the current connections as NTLM is OK. Another note: Most of our current SQL authentication is via SQL and not through AD. So, my assumption is that our main systems will not have a problem. Currently my main concern is SQL to SQL (and custom calling apps or Access Databases).

Comment: You likely have this query already: select session_id, net_transport, protocol_type, auth_scheme, client_net_address from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@SPID                    Useful in trouble-shooting authentication issues over linked servers.